# django-countries not using aws static folder

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm setting up a django project with the static files on AWS.  I am using `django-countries` to show country flags.

It works fine locally, but when I put it on a server I am using an AWS S3 bucket for the static files.  When I try and show the flag within a template, using `<img class="flag-img" src="{{ object.country.flag }}"/>` it doesn't show a flag and if I inspect the object it is showing `/static/flags/za.gif` as the url for the flag.

All other static files are showing `https://s3-bucket-name.s3.amazonaws.com/static/app_name/css/style.css`

What do I need to amend?

Comment: You should use something like `{% static object.country.flag %}` instead of `{{ object.country.flag }}` if you want to refer to static files. Have you set [`COUNTRIES_FLAG_URL`](https://github.com/SmileyChris/django-countries#customize-the-flag-url)?

Comment: I've missed `COUNTRIES_FLAG_URL`.  Just working out how to set it

Comment: If you use the `{% static %}` tag as I suggested, then you might not need to set `COUNTRIES_FLAG_URL`.

Comment: No, it needed `COUNTRIES_FLAG_URL` to be set